# using the <> operator for not equal to in sas with text

Tags: sas

I just started a new job where im learning sas and had a question about the <> operator. From my reading this does not equate to "Not equal to" but a type of MAX function.

However in one of the programs in my new place they are using it as a not equal to between two text values e.g. 'current'<> 'current', contained in an IF. Is this correct? does it differ if its text?

Comment: Can you show more of this code in which the max operator `<>` is used in an `IF` statement ?

Comment: Hi @Richard, **else if check1<>'a) Current' and check2='Y' and check3='Cao**

Comment: It's perfectly fine to edit your own question and add more material.  You could add your comment information at the bottom of the question as * For example * and the code as a code block.  You should also run code and post log messages as in @Tom answer that has example code showing important NOTE:  --- The *new place* certainly looks like it has some code with scary (bad coder) issues! Best practice is to make sure you have a source code version control system and a testing framework in place before you go fixing things.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, Tom's answer definitely helps. Now the trick is trying to tell the original coder, with years of SAS experience, that he may be wrong or to use better methods.

Comment: There's a stack overflow for that too, haha! Happy Journeys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As part of support for SQL syntax SAS had to adjust to allow `<>` to mean not equal in SQL code.  When they extended the `WHERE` statement to work in almost all situations they used the library they used for the SQL implementation.  So in PROC SQL code and WHERE statements `<>` means not equal.  But in data step code it still means MAX.

So if you use `<>` in an `IF` statement then you are requesting the MAX operator instead of the NOT EQUALS operator.

```
57   data _null_;
58     str='Hi';
59     if str <> 'Hi' then put 'TRUE'; else put 'FALSE';
NOTE: The "<>" operator is interpreted as "MAX".
60   run;

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by:
      (Line):(Column).
      59:10
NOTE: Invalid numeric data, 'Hi' , at line 59 column 10.
FALSE
str=Hi _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
```

Answer (score 4):

Ahh, yes.  `<>` is a max operator and `><` is a min operator.  Unless you are using a `WHERE` clause then `<>` means "not equal"...

Confusing?  Yes.

FWIW - For clarity in my code I use `min()` and `max()` and `^=`.  That way there is no confusion for new people reading my code.

Here is the documentation on operators in SAS.  About 2/3's the way down you will see the relevant section:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p00iah2thp63bmn1lt20esag14lh.htm

Comment: Thanks @DomPazz, what if its in an If Then decision making statement, does that fall under the Where clause also?

Comment: The MIN and MAX functions are not the same as the MIN and MAX operators.  I'm guessing you rarely use the MIN or MAX operators.  Using mnemonic operators is a good idea for all expressions.

Comment: @data_null_ , not for string comparison, no.  @Barry, if you have an `IF` statement then it is "MAX" and if you have a `WHERE` then it is "not equal to"